# Add / Remove field select - Añadir campo de formulario select en vez de input

Tags: javascript

al armar un formulario con la funcion de añadir y remover campo con jquery.
Lo tome de un caso similar y funciona bien con input, pero me resultaría mejor que el campo sea un select.
Intente hacerlo pero sin exito.

tambien cree el caso en jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/hernan527/xud9h0g8/6/#collaborate

gracias por su colaboracion

```
<div class="row">
<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/p5mlgajj54r6b1y/Sigmas.gif?dl=0" id="AddMoreFileBox" height="42" width="42">
<select class="form-control" type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_1" />
<option selected disabled>Opciones</option>
<option value="Sin Opcion">Sin Opcion</option>
<option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
<option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
<option value="3">Opcion 3</option></select>
<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" id="InputsWrapper">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 1; //maximum extra input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

//on add input button click
$(AddButton).click(function (e) {
    //max input box allowed
    if(x <= MaxInputs) {
        FieldCount++; //text box added ncrement
        //add input box
        $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vaas3wyluypptgn/sigmenos.gif?dl=0" class="removeclass" height="42" width="42" ><a href="#" class="removeclass"></a><select class="form-control" name="mytext[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'"/><option selected disabled>Opciones</option><option value="Sin Opcion">Sin Opcion</option><option value="1">Opcion 1</option><option value="2">Opcion 2</option><option value="3">Opcion 3</option></select></div>');
        x++; //text box increment

        $("#AddMoreFileId").show();

        $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");

        // Delete the "add"-link if there is 2fields.
        if(x == 2) {
            $("#AddMoreFileId").hide();
            $("#lineBreak").html("<br>");
        }
    }
    return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox

            $("#AddMoreFileId").show();

            $("#lineBreak").html("");

            // Adds the "add" link again when a field is removed.
            $('AddMoreFileBox').html("Add field");
    }
return false;
}) 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Hernan. No me quedó muy claro qué es lo que estás tratando de hacer, si puedes explicar un poco mejor qué quieres obtener y qué es lo que estás obteniendo quizá pueda ayudarte, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la línea de `$(InputsWrapper).append...` por:

```
$(InputsWrapper).append('<div><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vaas3wyluypptgn/sigmenos.gif?dl=0" class="removeclass" height="42" width="42" ><a href="#" class="removeclass"></a><select class="form-control" name="mytext[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'"><option selected disabled>Opciones</option><option value="Sin Opcion">Sin Opcion</option><option value="1">Opcion 1</option><option value="2">Opcion 2</option><option value="3">Opcion 3</option></select></div>');
```

Literal te sobra el caracter "/" después de `+ FieldCount +`

Comment: Excelente, gracias